# SVN checkout over secure http fails with Memory Fault

Tags: linux, svn, https, openssl

I built subversion client (1.6.5) along with its required dependency libs on SuSe 10.
I am trying to access our central repository server over https a secured URL.
But when i run the svn checkout command giving proper credentials it gives me memory fault.

What is that i have missed in building SVN or is that something to do with set up @ client side?

I run make check to confirm the subversion client build, firts 30 tests is succesful.

And also svn co over http:"URL" errs out with proper message for we do not have any repository over that URL.Does this mean the build is good but something to do with openssl library configuration?

### svn --version gives what all clients it supports and found that it  was supporting only http.I rebuilt the subversion with correct config options and currently has following options:

svn, version 1.6.5 (r38866)
   compiled Sep  8 2009, 18:05:39

Copyright (C) 2000-2009 CollabNet.
Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.tigris.org/
This product includes software developed by CollabNet (http://www.Collab.Net/).

The following repository access (RA) modules are available:

- ra_neon : Module for accessing a repository via WebDAV protocol using Neon.

  - handles 'http' scheme
  - handles 'https' scheme
- ra_svn : Module for accessing a repository using the svn network protocol.

  - handles 'svn' scheme
- ra_local : Module for accessing a repository on local disk.

  - handles 'file' scheme
- ra_serf : Module for accessing a repository via WebDAV protocol using serf.

  - handles 'http' scheme

    ### - handles 'https' scheme

but still no luck.I will be creating a local and http repository to check the same.

Comment: no rpms used..built using source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to rebuild openssl with "no-asm" configuration setting and subversion started working for "https" repository.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing a pre-built binary?  Does it give you any other errors?  Hard to determine your problem without more details ... plenty of people use the SVN client on SUSE Linux without any problems.

Comment: I have built using source code no rpm is used to install any deps 
libs.

Comment: I think LuckyLindy wanted to suggest that you try the same checkout using a pre-build library. That way you could test if the error is caused by your built version or by something else...

Comment: unfortunately i cannot upload/install any binaries on the machine.

Comment: If you're tired of burning time, you could always set up a shared drive on SUSE and map to that shared drive from Windows.  Then on Windows install TortoiseSVN and checkout to your SUSE shared drive.  We have one developer who does something like this, although more for philosophical reasons than technical.